# cURL library no longer works with current CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, curl

I would like to know please how to correct the following error, or what an alternative solution would be.

**Update 1** - In my php.ini from `extension=php_curl.dll` is uncommented (I've rebooted the server too), however Curl does not appear anywhere in `PHPINFO()`.

**Update 2** - Furthermore, I'm certain I'm looking at the right `php.ini` because it's the one mentioned in`PHPINFO()` as *Loaded Configuration File*.

I'm trying to perform simple cURL calls from within CodeIgniter using Phil Sturgeon's [library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl).

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.3.

I get the following error when performing the [first example](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl#simple-calls) straight from the official README.

[image: Error message]

Here is my controller class:

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index() {

        $this->load->library('curl');

        // Simple call to remote URL
        echo $this->curl->simple_get('http://google.com/');

    }

}

/* End of file test.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/test.php */
```

Comment: it looks like php isn't installed with the curl module

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed the most recent wampserver 2.2 over my (few months old) wampserver installation (and chose 32bit this time instead of 64bit), and curl seems to be working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

Did you first install the `php curl` extension.

Please visit http://php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php for instructions on doing this.

Here is a guide for windows http://devilsworkshop.org/tutorial/enabling-curl-on-windowsphpapache-machine/702/

After doing this, make sure you **restart** your `Apache` web server

Comment: I've followed that guide but the issue remains.

Comment: Just wanted to mention I did a hard reboot of the system also.

Comment: Sometimes you could have **1 or more** `php.ini` files. Make sure you find them all and change this `;extension=php_curl.dll` to `extension=php_curl.dll` then **restart apache**

Comment: Yes, I confirmed the php.in in PHPINFO() before doing that. The issue remains still.